# Please explain how to find the Christoffel symbols

Tags: tensors, general-relativity

Given tensor:
$$g = \begin{pmatrix}
g_{00} & g_{01}\\ 
g_{10} & g_{11}
\end{pmatrix}$$

I need to find, for example, this:  $\Gamma^1_{10}$ What does this mean and how to do it? What is the difference between $\Gamma^0_{10}$ and $\Gamma^1_{10}$? I understood it in this way: $\Gamma^1_{10} = g_{10}$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Succinctly
$$\Gamma^1{}_{10}=
\frac{1}{2}g^{10}[g_{00,1}+g_{10,0}-g_{10,0}]+ 
\frac{1}{2}g^{11}[g_{10,1}+g_{01,0}-g_{10,1}]$$
where $g_{00,1}=\frac{g_{00}}{\partial x^1}$ for example.
The $g^{ij}$ are the entries of $g^{-1}$.

This can be simplified to
$$\Gamma^1{}_{10}=
\frac{1}{2}g^{10}g_{00,1}+ 
\frac{1}{2}g^{11}g_{01,0}.$$